# 180V voltage reference

Tags: voltage-reference

I have a 195-210V(with ripple) power supply and I need a 180V voltage reference.

This is my best idea so far:

[image: ref]

Instead of just connecting a resistor and 180V zener diode in series, I do it two times to get better ripple rejection.

(two zener diodes on the left of course have greater total voltage drop that diode on the right).

This solution is still far from ideal, but it's not very bad.
I think there are better solutions, but I couldn't find or invent them myself.
One obvious solution that has better accuracy would be to connect a few smaller voltage reference integrated circuits in series, and final result probably would still have better accuracy than zener diodes. However this is not a good solution since it would require much more compenents, and zener diode solution ony has 5 components.

Are there better solutions that don't require much more components?

Comment: How accurate is accurate?

Comment: Which are you **most concerned about?**: (1) ripple. (2) DC average voltage accuracy.

Comment: @user253751 Zener diode solution has 0.4Vp-p ripple in my circuit. Therefore anything that could do better is considered accurate.

Comment: @glen_geek average DC voltage could actually be anything from 176 to 184V. Important thing is that it should be as constant as possible.

Comment: Another option is to try and amplify a small voltage reference. I don't know if they make high voltage op-amps, but you could use a transistor buffer on the output, and a voltage divider in the feedback circuit.

Comment: Just put a capacitor of some reasonable value across the zener or, split the 10 kohm resistor in two and put the capacitor at the centre point to ground. What frequency is the ripple and what accuracy for the voltage reference?

Comment: @Andyaka ripple is 100Hz, but voltage supply also contains 20Hz-20kHz AC component that comes from load variations. Circuit presented in question achieves accuracy of about +-0.4V on my simulation.

Comment: @user253751 Sorry, I meant 0.8Vp-p, not 0.4(however I don't think it's a huge difference)

Comment: @JK It's "old tech" but have you considered selecting out a few NE-2 bulbs for this purpose. You would need to test them and find the right group to hit that range. But since no one mentioned it yet, I thought I might. I have used them in a string for still higher voltages.